# Knuckle push-ups vs Finger push-ups

Tags: push-ups, calisthenics, wrist, bones, fingers

I was wondering which one is better, knuckle push ups or finger push ups. I know that knuckle push ups strengthen your wrists, and finger pushups strengthen your fingers. But is it better to do them both in one session? flip-flop between them (knuckle pushups on one day and finger pushups on the next, then knuckles again and so on), or doing one of them exclusively?

What I'm building up to do is

Diamond pushups

normal knuckle push ups

finger wide grip pushups

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long and short of it is that neither is *better* than the other. They're different.

Any and all training should have elements of variety, and you should definitely be doing both of these variations, and more. Many more. In fact, here's a video displaying some 30 variations, grouped by difficulty level: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqPe_iAm8lI

I wouldn't advise you do them all in one session. I'd say pick 5-6 variations each time, and keep it fun!